# add markers as vector tile with MapBox Studio

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I have some GeoJSON data containing some locations I'd like to show on my map.
Since it contains also the style (marker-icon, marker-size, etc.), right now I am using this data as

```
map.setGeoJSON(my_data);
```

These locations will never change, I want to add them as a Vector Tile. Is there a way to do that with MapBox studio?
I tried to put my_data in a file and load it in MBS, but I don't know how to style them as they were the default markers of MapBox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Since it contains also the style (marker-icon, marker-size, etc.)

Do you mean it follows MapBox's [simplestyle spec](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geojson-simplestyle/)?  If so, this simplestyle is only intended to style geojsons in the browser, not vector tile sources in MapBox Studio.

If you want to style them in MapBox Studio, you have to use CartoCSS: create a Studio Source project with your geojson, and create a Studio Style project to style them w/ Carto.  Checkout the [maki icon set](https://www.mapbox.com/maki/) and reference the icons you want for each point using the `marker-file: url("path/to/icon.png");` property.

Otherwise, you can load the geojson into your map in the browser using mapbox.js and apply their simplestyles.

Comment: I have really a bunch of markers to add.... so I think put them in a vector tile is a good solution. I don't think MBS follows the _simplestyle spec_ ... at least, I didn't manage to make it work. I'd like to know if there is a way to do that. If I use the `marker-file:url("");`  I should have an image for each color and icon...

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to make MapBox Studio use the *simplestyle spec*.  So, in Studio, you're stuck using CartoCSS.  Use `marker-file:url("path/to/icon.png");` Carto property, and point it to the path to your icon png--if you want to mimic the icon set of the simplestyle spec, check out **Maki**, linked above .  [This Studio guide](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/style-manual/) gives a good example of how to set up your style project directory to store icons.

Comment: For guidance, check out the **OSM Bright 2** project that's included in MapBox Studio.  It uses Maki icons for points-of-interest in a pretty cleaver way by specifying the icon name as an attribute of each marker feature: `marker-file:url('icon/[maki]-12.svg');`